# Unicode character for PUZZLE PIECE?

Tags: unicode

Is there an Unicode symbol representing puzzle pieces? There are lots of seldomly used dingbats in Unicode, and I sort of don't really remember - but suspect there's one for this too. However, I couldn't find anything like it in gucharmap, because it's probably not complete (lacks Klingon!). And neither in the tables on unicode.org/charts/ - there's too much to look through manually..

So, has anybody seen a PUZZLE character?

Alternative question: What else would you use as symbol for application plugins?

Comment: It's a popular myth that Unicode include Klingon characters.  In fact the proposal was rejected - http://unicode.org/consortium/utc-minutes/UTC-087-200105.html

Comment: And no there is no Unicode 'puzzle piece' character but if you want to search through Unicode character names, you might find http://liip.to/unicode useful.

Comment: @Grant McLean: So, I've fallen for this myth too ;) Anyway, found the rejected proposals list (and the Klingon reference) while browsing unicode.org a while. So there's clearly no such puzzle piece yet. But Unicode 6.0.0 adds a truck load of silly emoticons, so they must be pretty accepting; therefore I'll just go and request my puzzle piece for Unicode 7.. Or maybe it's already in one of the private use character ranges.. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Given that Unicode contains stupid 'characters' such as &x1F4A9; and &x1F4AA;, requesting for a puzzle piece doesn't seem excessive.

Comment: As in 'jigsaw puzzle'. Not chess, tile-sliders, sokaban, tic-tac-toe, Minesweeper...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Unicode Consortium [doesn't list a puzzle character](https://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt).

And really, even if it did, I'm not sure you should use it.  It relies on that glyph being available in the font you're distributing, and that's far from a sure thing, especially for the more obscure characters.

This is, for me, the canonical "plugin icon":

[image: Plugin Icon]

And I can think of two routes to go:

- **If you're sold on having it be a character** you can create your own font, using [Fontlab](https://www.fontlab.com/) or something similar, then distribute the font along with your app.  It turns out to be easier than it might seem.  This has the advantage that you can treat the "plugin" picture just as another piece of text.
- **Better may be to just use an graphic**.  Including a graphic is easier, and works just as well if you're trying to use it for an icon or button.

Comment: Since my applications main plattform is Linux and Win a second class port, the font issue isn't that bad. Distributing an own font would even be within range, but at this point it would make more sense to just break up the label and really embed an image. - I've just thought I've seen a PUZZLE piece somewhere. And since Unicode lists five dozen domino dingbats and other random game stuff, just thought it might have this one too, appeared common enough to me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a character like this. At least, I've never seen one.

Note that if you are using Windows, you can just type `charmap.exe`, select an Unicode-compatible font, and view every available character. Probably similar tools are available for other operating systems too.

> What else would you use as symbol for application plugins?

Depending on the context, you can use different things. A plus `+` symbol may be the one which symbolizes probably the better the idea of a plug-in (IMHO even better than a piece of puzzle, since a plug-in is something which adds a feature to software, not a part which must be combined with other parts to form a whole application).

Why not using an icon? Keep in mind that using a fancy unicode character may cause some problems with non-unicode-compatible software, browsers and environments.

Comment: There isn't a single typeface in existence that provides *every* glyph defined in Unicode - so all you'll be seeing is every available character *in that typeface*.

Comment: Not using Windows, so mentioned gucharmap. It looks up a specific Unicode font on BSD/Linux if the default font misses a character. It's rather encyclopedical, but still not 100% finished.

Comment: @caf: yeah, you're right. Like mario said in his question, either viewer tools are incomplete, or there are tons of characters to look through.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode 11.0, released June 5, 2018, added a character for a puzzle piece: `U+1F9E9`.

See the [Emoji page](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts-11.0/emoji-released.html#1f9e9) for a visual reference.

Software support isn't so great at the moment as this depends on updated fonts. But most social networks do support it already.

Answer (score 1):

[This UniView Unicode database search tool](http://rishida.net/scripts/uniview/) allows you to search for Unicode characters by their name. E.g. try typing "snowman" into the "Search text" box, and see what you get.

No results for "puzzle", sorry to say!

Answer (score 1):

For a plugin [an electric plug (U+1F50C)](http://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%94%8C) character may be used.
It is not semantically close, but at least has verbal association.